# DTD Validation on XML Files

Tags: xml

I started learning XML yesterday but I cant get around the concept of DTD.

My thinking is that, this will cause an error since my picture tag contains a whitespace character and I explicitly mention in my DTD that this should contain only EMPTY element.

As per my understanding, empty element does not contain any character at all.  Whitespace is a character I think.

But I am not sure why my eclipse editor is not displaying an error related to this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE person [
<!ELEMENT person (picture) >
<!ELEMENT picture  EMPTY >
]>
<person>

 <picture></picture>

</person>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you've posted doesn't actually include any whitespace which is why it validates just fine. If you had something like this:

```
<person>
     <picture> </picture>
</person>
```

you would have whitespace. An empty element can be written as either `<picture/>` or `<picture></picture>`. They are equivalent.

Comment: so thats how it is.  Thanks.  My first impression was that it is still considered as a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to format the XML like

```
<person>
   <picture />
</person>
```

I don't think there is any whitespace in your picture element in your example which is why Eclipse won't throw an error.